# Sort grouped citations on unsorted style with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing, sorting

I'm trying to get sorted citations when they are in a group, that is, within a `\cite{}`, but unsorted or in order of appearance when they are called from different `\cite` macros.

Basically, what I want is not to worry about the group of citations that are within the macro, and sort them automatically.  Simultaneously, I would like to maintain the unsorted or other nature of the bibliography style.

I guessed that the `cite` package should take care of it.  But apparently it doesn't change the sorting scheme of the bibliography style in the unsorted case.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{a,
    author = {A},
    year = {2001},
    title = {A},
  }
  @book{b,
    author = {B},
    year = {2002},
    title = {B},
  }
  @book{c,
    author = {C},
    year = {2003},
    title = {C},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\cite{b,a,c}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

#### Current output

[image]

#### Expected output

[image]

Comment: I gave up on bitex and used biblatex instead: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464601/7561

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comment.