# Unsorted bibliography but locally sorted using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I'm trying to solve a rather odd sorting of the bibliography.  I want to have the numeric citations appear in order of citation.  However, I want to sort the group of references by another style.

I thought it will be similar to other problems: [The same bibliography with different sorting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258978/the-same-bibliography-with-different-sorting), but that solution is not working.

For instance, if I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee, citestyle=numeric-comp, sortcites, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{biblatex-ieee.bib}
    @book{candy1992,
      editor        = "J. C. Candy and G. C. Temes",
      title         = "Oversampling Delta-Sigma Data Converters Theory,
                       Design and Simulation",
      publisher     = "{IEEE} Press.",
      location      = "New York",
      year          = "1992"
    }
    @inbook{anderson2000,
      author        = "J. B. Anderson and K. Tepe",
      title         = "Properties of the Tailbiting {BCJR} Decoder",
      booktitle     = "Codes, Systems and Graphical Models",
      series        = "{IMA} Volumes in Mathematics and Its Applications",
      publisher     = "Springer-Verlag",
      location      = "New York",
      year          = "2000"  
    }   
    @book{bul1964,
      author        = "B. K. Bul",
      title         = "Theory Principles and Design of Magnetic Circuits",
      publisher     = "Energia Press",
      loction       = "Moscow",
      year          = "1964",
      pages         = "464",
      note          = "(in Russian)"
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{biblatex-ieee.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{candy1992, anderson2000} \cite{bul1964}

\newrefcontext[sorting=none]
\printbibliography[title=Unsorted]

\end{document}
```

I obtain

[image]

while I was expecting

[image]

That is, to get the consecutive citations to be cited in order of appearance.  But the contents of the each citation to be sorted (by a particular scheme).

Is there a way to achieve that using biblatex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as Biber is concerned two entries that were both first cited in the same `\cite` have the same precedence when sorting with `sorting=none` (i.e. `\sort{\citeorder}`), a tie is broken by taking the order in which the entries were cited within that `\cite` into account. But you can also break the tie differently by adding other sort features, for example a copy of what `nyt` does. This was implemented following [BibLaTeX: how to sort references by year within the citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55256/35864) and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/5 in https://github.com/plk/biber/commit/f74af1c946675b829e19743dd77ad62aec901f3d. Just define the sorting scheme `nonenyt` as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee, citestyle=numeric-comp, sortcites]{biblatex}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{nonenyt}{
  \sort{\citeorder}
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{sorting=nonenyt}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{candy1992,
  editor        = {J. C. Candy and G. C. Temes},
  title         = {Oversampling Delta-Sigma Data Converters Theory,
                   Design and Simulation},
  publisher     = {{IEEE} Press.},
  location      = {New York},
  year          = {1992},
}
@inbook{anderson2000,
  author        = {J. B. Anderson and K. Tepe},
  title         = {Properties of the Tailbiting {BCJR} Decoder},
  booktitle     = {Codes, Systems and Graphical Models},
  series        = {{IMA} Volumes in Mathematics and Its Applications},
  publisher     = {Springer-Verlag},
  location      = {New York},
  year          = {2000},
}
@book{bul1964,
  author        = {B. K. Bul},
  title         = {Theory Principles and Design of Magnetic Circuits},
  publisher     = {Energia Press},
  loction       = {Moscow},
  year          = {1964},
  pages         = {464},
  note          = {(in Russian)},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{candy1992, anderson2000} \cite{bul1964}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "[1, 2] [3]" and in the bibliography 1: J. B. Anderson and K. Tepe, 2: J. C. Candy and G. C. Temes, Eds., 3: B. K. Bul]